# How to install Free ( liscenced with a key) Bitdefender antivirus from terminal in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, antivirus

Could anyone please give me instructions how to install free Bitdefender antivirus (with a Personal License key obtained via mail) from terminal in Ubuntu 16.04? (The case of installing "bitdefender non-free" doesn't fit.)
...
I am trying to install the product named "Bitdefender Antivirus Scanner for Unices" of which I have been given yesterday Aug.17,2016 via email a free Personal License key (for personal use only), after having contacted 
http://www.bitdefender.com/business/antivirus-for-unices.html
and requesting a Free Licence.
I have downloaded 3 possible suitable installation files and tried (in vain!) to run the first and appearing most applicable one to my system of AMD-64bits-PC with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run

...
The other two canditate files not tested yet are:

BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.ipk.run

and

BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.rpm.run

...I don't know if they are applicable.

Comment: Why from terminal only?

Comment: Well, on Ubuntu, you should chose `BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run`.  Open your terminal, make sure you are in the folder where this file is stored.  At that point, make sure the file is executable:  `chmod 755 BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run`.  At that point I'd try to execute the file `./BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run`.  That's my best guess on how it should be done.  Good luck.

Comment: I have tried and didn't succeed, but I am a beginner and I study how to handle the problem. I have installed a gufw firewall instead. Anyway thank you very much. When I will have results I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I use Headless Ubuntu 16.04 Server on all my web servers. Primary setup is AMP with Postfix and Dovecot. My clients get a lot of viruses via email.. so initially, i have a daily cron setup for CLAMWV to scan /vat/vmail/* (All the Virtual Mail Folders).

If you, like me have a few VPS servers, BitDefender community seems quite good... Couple things I do though..

1. log in via ssh as root
2. `cd /tmp`
3. ```
   wget http://download.bitdefender.com/SMB/Workstation_Security_and_Management/BitDefender_Antivirus_Scanner_for_Unices/Unix/Current/EN_FR_BR_RO/Linux/BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run
   ```
4. `chmod +x BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run`
5. ./BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.deb.run`
6. read some of the T's & C's.. I usually hit CTRL-C - and immediately after type "accept" (without the inverted commas).
7. It should install bdscan. If you have a GUI instance, bdgui is there too. (The path: `/opt/BitDefender-scanner/bin/`)
8. type `bdscan --update`
9. type `bdscan [where you want to scan]` and then the options. e.g.
   `bdscan /var/vmail/* --action=disinfect` (to attempt a disinfect)..

There are quite a few options. If the disinfect isnt thorough.. perhaps a quarantine?

Hope this helps.

Andreas

PS I never bother with the license key, as it wont word if you are using a web server. But for home use.. sure.